# how to smooth an embeded image in flex when its embed as a class for textinput border style

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, actionscript-3, styling, textinput

Hello my fellow stackoverflower,

i'm looking for away to smooth an image of and embed png file.
i'm using the embeded png as the borderskin for my textInput.

i have seen some other postings about this subject but i can figure it out. Does anybody have an idea, how i can a complish this? some real solid code example wwould be nice.

this is what i would like to do.

step 1) embed and image

```
    [Embed(source='assets/images/searchBoxImg.png')]
    private var searchBG:Class;
```

step 2) smooth the image somehow?

step 3) and us it as a borderskin for my textInput.

```
        this.setStyle('borderSkin',searchBG);
```

is there anybody out there that can help me with this?

DJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i finelly found a solution. Actually is pretty simpel to smooth and embeded image in a class.

Step one) create an new actionscript class that extends BitmapAsset.

Step two) Embed and image and set smoothing to true

```
package 
{
    import mx.core.BitmapAsset;

    [Embed(source='assets/images/searchBoxImg.png')]
    public class searchBG extends BitmapAsset
    {
        public function searchBG()
        {
            smoothing = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Step three) Create a new as3 class and import the first class.

now you are able to use the searchBG Class on the borderSkin.

```
this.setStyle('borderSkin', searchBG);
```

thats it.

Answer (score 1):

No need to do much for smoothing image just

[Embed(source='assets/images/searchBoxImg.png'),smoothing='true']

Comment: the Embed parameter is 'smoothing', not 'smooth'

Answer (score -1):

The answer from Chris is in principle right.
The correct syntax is:

```
[Embed(source='assets/images/searchBoxImg.png',smoothing='true')]
```

Comment: This should have been a comment once you gain enough reputation. I fixed that now in the answer, so you can remove this.